# How can I return a stackpanel element from a ValueConverter and get it to display properly

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have a datagrid that i'm binding to, and I have a valueConverter that i send an object to in hopes of returning an image with some text after it(which is put inside a stackpanel). However, upon displaying all I see in the gridview cell is System.Windows.Control.StackPanel.

Here is the xaml. I am binding the GrieView ItemsSource correctly and the value coming into the converter is correct.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True">
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Text" />
 </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

This is basically exactly what the converter does.

```
StackPanel stackpanel = new StackPanel();
stackpanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
stackpanel.Children.Add(Adds a UI element);

TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = appendingText;
stackpanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
return stackpanel;
```

but in the gridviewCell all that shows is a string reading System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A GridViewDataColumn doesn't know how to interpret a StackPanel as "data" and just calls its ToString method. You should probably use a basic GridViewColumn with an appropriate CellTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `GridViewColumn` and bind the `Content` property of a `ContentControl` using your converter:

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn IsReadOnly="True">
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Text" />
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.Header>
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```